# Printing dropshadow and other WPF effects

Tags: wpf, printing, effects

I am working on a WPF application where the user can print multipage reports.  I am using the DocumentPaginator which is working well for the most part.  That is until I introduce any sort of effect such as the built in dropshadow or a brightness/contrast effect I have.  I am guessing it has something to do with the lack of pixelshader built into printers.  Any suggestions for a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You could render the UI to a bitmap](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/10/Rendering-a-WPF-Container-to-Bitmap) and then print an Image that refers to the  bitmap.