# Can I print pixel shader effect?

Tags: wpf, printing, screenshot, pixel-shader

I have a WPF user control that I want to print. I am able to do that with XpsDocumentWriter. Now I would like to apply a pixel shader effect. I can see the effect has been applied on the control. However when I try to print it, the output is the same as the one without the effect. Is it possible to print shader effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous identical questions of StackOverflow have indicated that this is not possible:

[Printing dropshadow and other WPF effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982306/printing-dropshadow-and-other-wpf-effects)

The best solution to this problem is to [render the UI to a bitmap](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/10/Rendering-a-WPF-Container-to-Bitmap) and then print an Image that refers to the  bitmap.